# yii2 user CRUD create or update with password

Tags: module, yii2, crud, gii

I have a User model that stores the users in the database. With GII create a CRUD to be able to register and update users. The problem is with the password.
How could I do for when I create a user to load a password and when I update it if I want to be able to update it?

My table:

> CREATE TABLE `user` (
>     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>     `auth_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
>     `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `password_reset_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
>     `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
>     `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

My form:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper; 
use app\models\Role; 

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="user-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'role_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Role::find()->all(),'id','description'),
            ['prompt'=> Yii::t('app', 'Select...')]
    )?> 

    <?= $form->field($model, 'newPassword')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'), 'value' => ''])->label('') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkBox(['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Status'), 'selected' => $model->status])?>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Permission;
use app\models\search\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * UserController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index','view','update','create','delete'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                            return Permission::hasAllowed($action->controller->id,$action->id);
                        }
                    ],                  
                ],
            ],      
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all User models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single User model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new User model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Successful create!'));            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Successful update!'));            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing User model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return User the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    /*
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
    */

    public function behaviors() 
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at']
                ],
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ]; 
    }   

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status', 'role_id', 'username','email'], 'required'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
            [['role_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Role::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['role_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

    public static function isActive()
    {
        return Yii::$app->user->identity->status == self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    }   

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Role::className(), ['id' => 'role_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'status' => Yii::t('app', 'Status Active'),
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the beforeSave Event in your User model

```
  public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if ($insert) {
            $this->setPassword($this->password_hash);
        } else {
            if (!empty($this->password_hash)) {
                $this->setPassword($this->password_hash);
            } else {
                $this->password_hash = (string) $this->getOldAttribute('password_hash');
            }
        }
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```

and update the update action in your controller

```
/**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $model->setAttribute('password_hash', null);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Successful update!'));            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

and update your form view field to

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'), 'value' => ''])->label(false) ?>
```

update your user model validations rules

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status', 'role_id', 'username','email'], 'required'],
            ['password_hash', 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],
            ['password_hash', 'string'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
            [['role_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Role::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['role_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Dont I need change de view form?

    <?= $form->field($model, 'newPassword')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'), 'value' => ''])->label('') ?>

Comment: I try this solution but never update the password when the field is not empty.

Comment: yes your form should have  <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'), 'value' => ''])->label('') ?> you dont have to introduce a new field

Comment: I applied this change, but when I want change the password it dont change. Can you help me to solve that please? thanks.

Comment: i just noticed that you don't have a validation rule in your model for the password_hash, i have updated my answer above