# Yii2 create or update user profile

Tags: yii2, crud, yii2-basic-app

In my basic app, I have a User model and a UserForm model that stores and update the users in the database. Now, I got problem when updating the user profile. It feedbacks 'Successful update!' even though the new data won't save.

My table:

```
Table name: User
Attributes: id, fname, mname, lname, address, username, auth_key, password_hash, password_reset_token, email, status, created_at, updated_at
```

My Model:

```
class UserForm extends Model
{
    public $fname;
    public $mname;
    public $lname;
    public $address;
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password_hash;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['fname', 'required'],
            ['fname', 'trim'],

            ['mname', 'trim'],

            ['lname', 'required'],
            ['lname', 'trim'],

            ['address', 'required'],
            ['address', 'trim'],
            ['address', 'string', 'max' => 255],

            ['username', 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 4, 'max' => 255],   

            ['email', 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password_hash', 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],
            ['password_hash', 'string', 'min' => 8],
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if ($insert) {
            $this->setPassword($this->password_hash);
        } else {
            if (!empty($this->password_hash)) {
                $this->setPassword($this->password_hash);
            } else {
                $this->password_hash = (string) $this->getOldAttribute('password_hash');
            }
        }
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->setAttribute('password_hash', null);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Successful update!'));            
        return $this->redirect(['overview']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

protected function findModel($id) {
    if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

My view.php

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'fname')->textInput(['autofocus' => true])->label('First Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'mname')->textInput()->label('Middle Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'lname')->textInput()->label('Last Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'), 'value' => ''])->label(false) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Some of the steps are from here: [yii2 user CRUD create or update with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840852/yii2-user-crud-create-or-update-with-password])

Comment: How your `findModel()` looks like?

Comment: `protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserForm` is never used. Your `findModel()` returns `User`, so all validation and saving is handled by `User` model - I guess it does not have any validation rules, so `$model->load()` does not load anything.

You may try to extend your form model from active record model:

```
class UserForm extends User
```

And use it in `findModel()` or create separate method for returning form model:

```
protected function findFormModel($id) {
    if (($model = UserForm::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Then use this method in your `update` action. Don't forget to remove old properties from `UserForm` - they're unnecessary and may break attributes behavior.